# Ubuntu 14.04 Access point

Tags: wireless, wireless-access-point

I am trying to activate my access point on Ubuntu to share the cable University connection with my mobile phone.

But I get zapped by the following:

```
"(32) Access Point (AP) mode is not supported by this device."
```

I tried to check the HW and apparently it should be ok, see below the `iw list` output. It seems to me that this Wlan-card should support the AP mode.

Any idea on what I could try?/where I can find other drivers?/why this happens?

---

```
~$ iw list(snipped)

        Supported TX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
     * Unknown mode (10): 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
Supported RX frame types:
     * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * managed: 0x40 0xd0
     * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
     * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
     * Unknown mode (10): 0x40 0xd0
```

Answer (score 0):

You Have to run a command in terminal "iw list" ( If Not Installed - Run sudo aptitude install iw)

> After Running "iw list" command you will listing like

```
Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
         * mesh point
```

If cant see AP then,you can't use the AP mode

Comment: I did, the output (snipped) was in the question above. Apparently it is, but yet I get the error.